# Does a domain DFS root have to be \\somedomain.com or can it be \\arbitraryname.somedomain.com?

Tags: windows, dfs, windows-server-2008

Does a domain DFS root have to be `\\example.com` or can it be `\\arbitraryname.example.com`?

DNS can still point `arbitraryname.example.com` to multiple servers — even domain controllers.

I want to point example.com to a corporate webserver.  I can't do this now because DFS clients go to example.com to connect to shares or resolve DFS queries (referrals).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a domain DFS root, then it has to be whatever the AD Domain is. It's possible your domain is `abc.example.com`, so that would also be the DFS root.

The only alternative is a standalone root, and that's based on the name of the server, which could be `server1.example.com`.

There are different features available for domain and standalone DFS roots however. Mainly that Domain DFS can have multiple roots for HA, where standalone can not. There are other details (mostly related to scalability).